# Error in Variable while trying to use Mail()

Tags: php, email

I tried a ton of different ways to fix this issue, when I try to send the email if I fill the value 'name' just with one word it pass through and the email is sent. But if the 'name' value contains more than 1 word the error message shows up.

```
<?php
if( !isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['asunto']) || empty($_POST['asunto']) ||
    !isset($_POST['mensaje']) || empty($_POST['mensaje'])
){
    echo '<p>Please fill in all fields</p>';
}else{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $to = 'mail@hotmail.com'; 
    $from = 'From:' . $name . '';

    $subject = 'Mensaje de ' . $name . '';  
    $message = 'Nombre: ' . $name . '<br/><br/>
               Telefono: ' . $phone . '<br/><br/>
               Correo electronico: ' . $email . '<br/><br/> 
               Asunto: ' . $asunto . '<br/><br/>
               Mensaje: ' . nl2br($mensaje) . '<br/>';

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That's because "more than one word" is not a valid [mailbox list](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.2)

Comment: Are you sure you dont want `$from = 'From: ' . $email . '';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly What's the purpose of the empty string at the end?

Comment: @kojow7 Non as far as I can tell. But I didnt want to frighten the OP with a bigger change than necessary

Comment: Thanks both for your comments.

Comment: I'm still figuring out why it does not work now the variable email only pass if I fill it with 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

RiggsFolly was correct there was an error in the following line

Invalid

```html
$from = 'From:' . $name . '';
```

Valid

```html
$from = 'From: ' . $email . '';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$from = 'From: ' . $name. ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP';
```

Comment: This header is valid, but recipient's server can block such "simple" email header because consider of spam. Especially if "from email" has different domain than your sendmail (sender) domain.

Comment: Hello RAF, the code works when I only fill the form with one character and the email is sent but if I try to type real name, email, subject etc. the error shows up.